# How to solve the "DerValue.get OID, not an OID"?

Tags: java

I want to create a certificate with the certificate policy extension and use the following code.

```
CertificatePolicyId certificatePolicyId2=new CertificatePolicyId(new DerValue("2.5.29.32.1"));    
PolicyInformation policyInformation2=new PolicyInformation(certificatePolicyId2, null);    
List<PolicyInformation> policyInformations=new ArrayList<PolicyInformation>();   
policyInformations.add(policyInformation2);    
certificateExtensions.set(CertificatePoliciesExtension.NAME, new CertificatePoliciesExtension(policyInformations));
```

But an exception was thrown:

```
java.io.IOException: DerValue.getOID, not an OID 19
    at sun.security.util.DerValue.getOID(DerValue.java:447)
    at sun.security.x509.CertificatePolicyId.<init>(CertificatePolicyId.java:56)
```

How to set the `String arg0` of `new DerValue(String arg0)`?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the format of "2.5.29.32.1"? Otherwise, it appears you are setting arg0.

Comment: I tried "2.5.29.32.1", "2 5 29.32 0", "{2 5 29 32 0}" and "{2.5.29.32.0}", but failed.

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: sun.security.x509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sun.security.util.DerValue` (not x509) is basically a wrapper/holder for any of a dozen-plus types defined and encodable in ASN.1; the `DerValue(String)` constructor creates (a wrapper containing) only ASN.1 type `PrintableString` or `UTF8String` (not OID).

There is a different class `sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier` which specifically represents an OID, with a `(String)` constructor that parses that text format into an OID object:

```
 import sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier;
 ...
 ObjectIdentifier oid = new ObjectIdentifier ("2.5.29.32.1");
```

Comment: @ dave_thompson_085 Thanks! Could you give a code example to add the certificate policy extension (_policy id and user notice qualifier_) to a certificate? Thanks!

Comment: Before a PolicyQualifierInfo is added to a set of PolicyQualifierInfo, an object of PolicyQualifierInfo needs to be generated:  `PolicyQualifierInfo policyQualifierInfo1=new PolicyQualifierInfo(byte[] encoded)`.  How to declare the _parameter_ `byte[] encoded`?

Comment: @DOWTIA: the _declaration_ is obviously `byte[]`; the hard part is the value in it, namely (the bytes that make up) a DER encoding. This is a different Q, but [the ASN.1 definition in rfc5280](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.4) is complicated enough if the value is constant I would consider precomputing it and providing it as a literal sequence of bytes or a literal base64 string now that j8 can standardly decode that.